# Why does my animation freeze when returning to activity containing it?

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, imagebutton, freeze

I'm still sort of new with Android, so forgive me if it's an obvious mistake.  In this activity I'm using `ViewPager` to horizontally scroll through three layouts containing  an `ImageButton` that has an animated background depending on its current state.  When the button is pressed, it starts a new activity.  However, when I hit the back button to go back to the activity containing the animation from the new activity, sometimes the animation freezes or plays back faster than it should.  I wrote a method for starting up the animation that I use in `onWindowFocusChanged()`, and `onRestart()`.  I'm working in Android 2.1 (API 7).

This is my code:

```
public class CopyOfWorld extends Activity{

    MediaPlayer muzak;
    Boolean mSwitch = false;
    ImageButton holmes;
    AnimationDrawable holmesAnimation;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.world);

        Preferencer pp = (Preferencer)getApplicationContext();

        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter();
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(1);


        if(pp.getMuzak()){
            mSwitch = true;
            muzak = MediaPlayer.create(CopyOfWorld.this, R.raw.level1);
            muzak.setLooping(true);
            muzak.start();
        }
    }

    public void clicker(View v){
     Intent myIntent = new Intent(CopyOfWorld.this , Subworld.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
   }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        beginRender();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        if(mSwitch){
        muzak.release();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart(){
        super.onRestart();
        Preferencer pp = (Preferencer)getApplicationContext();
        if(pp.getMuzak()){
            muzak = MediaPlayer.create(CopyOfWorld.this, R.raw.level1);
            muzak.setLooping(true);
            muzak.start();
        }
        beginRender();
    }


    public void beginRender(){
        ImageButton holmes = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.subworlder);
        StateListDrawable background = (StateListDrawable) holmes.getBackground();
        Drawable current = background.getCurrent();
        if(current instanceof AnimationDrawable){
            holmesAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) current;
            holmesAnimation.start();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried calling the method `beginRender()` under `()onResume`, but then the app simply crashes.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT:

I've been tweaking the code here and there, unfortunately to no avail.  But I did notice a pattern in the behavior of the animation.  When I press down on the `ImageButton` or hold it so that it goes from its default animation to its pressed or focused animation then move my finger away from the button so that it doesn't start up the new activity, it sometimes behaves very much as I described at the beginning of this post (i.e. it's supposed to return to its default animation, but instead plays back at twice the rate, chokes up, or doesn't play at all.)

Currently the xml that contains these `ImageButton`s defines their `background`s as the animations and have no source (`src`).  But when I change the `background` to transparent and the `src` to the animations, the app crashes.

Any clues?